# Working through my first AJAX call - Stuck as to why my results aren't displaying at all

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Test it here - http://paulmatheson.net/webdev/wiki/wikipedia-viewer.html

Basically, you enter a term and the results are supposed to display below. I had it working for a second but changed something in the last hour or so and don't know where I screwed up. I've analyzed it and can't find the issue in the code. Can someone with a better eye/more experience help me out?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#random-btn').click(function() {
    window.open('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Random');
  });
  $('#submit-search-btn').click(function() {
    var searchTerm = $('#search-input').val();
    var url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&search=" + searchTerm + "&format=json&callback=?";

    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: url,
      async: false,
      dataType: "json",
      success: function(data) {
        var html;
        $('#header').html('<h5>Wiki Search</h5');
        $('.content').css('margin-top', '0');
        $('#div-random-btn').remove();

        for (var i = 0; i < data[1].length; i++) {
          html += "<div class='listing'><h4>" + data[1][i] + "</h4><h5>" + data[2][i] + "</h5></div>";
        };

        $("#output-div").html(html);
      },
      error: function(errorMessage) {}
    })
  })
});
```

That is the gist of the call. Please let me know if anything needs a more thorough break down.

Comment: Have you [checked your console?](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/javascript/185/getting-started-with-javascript/714/using-console-log) It might point you to the error.

Comment: Yes, the console is completely blank @MikeC

Comment: async false?  There's no reason for you to do that.  And plenty of reasons to change it (but not related to your missing content).

Comment: @James I followed a tutorial and that was recommended. What do you recommend?

Comment: Don't follow that tutorial.   async:false has been deprecated for at least five years (and wasn't supported for cross-domain requests in any case: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).  You can safely remove that line, it's not doing anything.

Comment: Yep just get rid of the line 3 under `$.ajax...`. that has `async: false,`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because your `button` is form element & its type is `submit`. So basically what's wrong is the form is submitted via form. Your ajax call is being cancelled due to this & page is reloading. You can do two things

1. You need to stop this event by using [preventDefault](https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/) method on button click like this

   `$('#submit-search-btn').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault()
        var searchTerm = $('#search-input').val();
        //Further code`
2. Change the button attribute to `type="button"` which will stop it from submitting in the first place

Comment: Wonderful! Another question - When I submit a search, the first result is undefined (well not even a result but undefined always goes on the page). Any idea why?

Comment: @pmath325 can you update on site so that i can check it . Try to do `var html = ''`

Comment: Yous a superstar. That fixed it (tested it at home)

Comment: @pmath325 Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted

Comment: Another option is to change it to `type="button"` so it doesn't submit the form.

Comment: @Barmar Yes just great ... simple alternate :). Thanks man!! Updated the answer