# Calling a controller action using AJAX with an anchor vs a button

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-core

I have a IActionResult on my controller that returns a Partial View via AJAX:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("/propertycoverages/loss")]
public IActionResult GetNewLoss()
{
    return PartialView("_Loss");
}
```

If I put an `<a>` tag in my Razor view with the following:

```
<a asp-controller="PropertyCoverages" asp-action="GetNewLoss" id="loss-btn" data-ajax="true" data-ajax-update="losses" data-ajax-success="addLoss" data-ajax-method="GET">Add</a>
```

the following HTML attribute gets generated in the `<a>` tag: `href="/propertycoverages/loss"`

it works as expected and the partial view is returned within the page. However, if I try to use a button:

```
<button asp-controller="PropertyCoverages" asp-action="GetNewLoss" id="loss-btn" type="submit" data-ajax="true" data-ajax-update="losses" data-ajax-success="addLoss" data-ajax-method="GET">Add</button>
```

the following HTML attribute gets generated in the `<button>` tag: `formaction="/propertycoverages/loss"`

and I get redirected to `/propertycoverages/loss` which is not what I want. **Is there a way I can make the button behave like the `<a>` tag**?

Note: These elements are inside a `<form>`. I also tried switching the `<button>` from `type="submit"` to `type="button"` but the controller action doesn't get called.

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/44269478/4018629

Comment: @AgamBanga I tried changing the button to type="button" but nothing happens when I click the button then. The controller action doesn't get called.

Comment: Why don't you attach a JS method to your button click again. In the JS method you can call back to the action get the HTML and lay in on the page in the AJAX call success method?

Comment: @DerekHackett this is probably what I will need to do. Thank you.

Comment: @RyanBuening Let me know if that works. If it does I will add it as an answer for you to pick.

Comment: @DerekHackett that is what I ended up doing. If you add an answer I will accept it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to attach a JavaScript method to your button click action.

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>
```

In the JS method you can call back to the action get the HTML and lay in on the page in the AJAX call success method.

```
    function onClick() {
    var url = [setURL];

        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: url,
            data: { },
            success: function (response) {
                $('#[setElementToReplace]').html(response);
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi  there are mainly three ways for calling the controller action from the submit button.

**Way1: Using simple Form**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("ActionName", "ControllerName"))
{
    <input type="submit" name="add" value="Add" />
    }
```

Note: By default it is a get request, If required you  can change formmethod = post

**Way 2:  Using  html Attributes**

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm())
{

 <input type="submit" name="add" value="Add" formaction="/anycontrollername/anyactionname" formmethod="get"
/>
}
```

Way 3 : using jquery

```
  @using (Html.BeginForm())
{

 <input type="submit" name="add" value="Add" id=”save”
/>
}

$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#save").click(function () {
        $("form").attr("action", "/anycontroller /anyaction");
    });
});
```

It seems that 2nd way will be suitable for your requirement,

Hope the above answer was useful.

Comment: I don't think I can have my button be of type="submit" when I want to do an AJAX call and stay on the page. I think I need to do something similar to what Derek suggested above and attach a JS method. Thank you.